# @csrf considered as normal html text

Tags: php, html, laravel

I usually use `@csrf` on `<form></form>` to by pass "Page Expired" message on Laravel, but now for some reason, it considered as just normal html text instead of code. I mean the "@csrf" literally shows up on the web page. Does anyone know the problem? It works normally on the other forms though

```
    <form method="POST" action="/user/usulan/post">
        @csrf
        <input type="text" name="nama" placeholder="Nama" required>
        <input type="text" name="tlp1" placeholder="tlp1" required>
        <input type="text" name="tlp2" placeholder="tlp2" required>
        <input type="text" name="usulan" placeholder="usulan" required>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your view file has `.blade.php` extension.